# Is anything on this list a tool I can use the enable some kind of disk encryption?

Tags: encryption, embedded, busybox, disk-encryption

I have a device running on some kind of obscure Linux distribution used for embedded devices. This device has a web gui where there is an option to enable encryption of the internal storage. However, that option is not available for me (my device is unsupported) so I have resorted to the command line. I had hoped `cryptsetup` would have been available, but it is not.

Below follows a list of all commands in the `$PATH` as well as one list with the output from `find / -ipath '*crypt*'`.

**Can anything on these lists be used to enable disk (volume) encryption?**

Commands in the `$PATH` (there are a couple of tools with crypt in their name, `pyrsa*` and `libcrypt-config`) are here https://pastebin.com/KcqpBfQk

Results from `find / -ipath '*crypt*'` https://pastebin.com/1C1Tuxgs

Notes

- There is no package manager, gcc and other basic tools in this distribution.
- A lot of the tools are just links to `Busybox`.

Comment: There's nothing interesting in `bin/` but then if the tools were there, how would you use them?

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov By finding some guide for them? However, after digging some more into this, I found ./rw/internal_apps/rainbow/filebrowser-45905a3/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/unicorn_api/v8/sv0/encryption/Encryption.py which looks interesting but I am not the right person to evaluate it. I have published the source here https://pastebin.com/ztwQFsr0 - can you say anything about this?

Comment: It's an HTTP library for python, i.e. it's useless for your usecase.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov Are you absolutely sure about that? The methods in the class are named `create_pool
    list_keyfile_storage
    generate_keyfile
    create_thinvolume
    create_volume
    lock_volume
    change_password
    unlock_volume` - it doesn't sound like http, does it?